# How do I get a detail view template to render in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I'm new to EmberJs and I'm trying to do something as simple as showing a detail view after selecting an item from a list.
I've set up [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wabbit/FdZUg/10/)

In the renderTemplate function of my route I'm doing console logging to see if the function is ever called. For my PostsRoute, it works, but I get no output from PostsDetailsRoute.renderTemplate

**Templates**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <table class='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    {{#each post in posts}}
                    <tr><td>
                            {{#linkTo details post.id}}{{post.title}}{{/linkTo}}
                        </td></tr>
                    {{/each}}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/details">
    {{post.description}}
</script>
```

**Routes**

```
App.PostsDetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function () {
        console.log('template PostsDetails rendered');
        this.render();
    }
});


App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    posts: [],
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set('posts', App.Post.find());
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        console.log('template Posts rendered');
        this.render();
    }

});
```

On a side note, what's the difference between uing data-template-name and id for handle bar templates with EmberJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

- In your router, you have defined `details` as resource, but your app uses it as a route. The difference between the two can be found in the [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/). Notice the difference in naming convention; if `details` is defined as a sub-resource, Ember will match it to the `DetailsController` controller. A resource is in fact what you want, but the contemporary theory is that it should simply be called `post`, and thus match up with `PostController`, `PostRoute`, etc.

Here's what your router would look like:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('posts', function () {
        this.route('post', { path: ':post_id' });
    });
});
```

- There is no `{{outlet}}` tag for your details to render into. You have a UI decision to make here: do post detail render below the index of posts, or on a new screen? If the former, you need to add an `{{outlet}}` tag to the `posts` template. If the latter, you need to replace the `posts` template with an `{{outlet}}` and move its present contents into the `posts/index` template.
- When linking to a route or resource, you should pass the actual model to the `{{linkto}}` helper, not the model's `id`.
- When you supply a model to the `post` route via `{{linkTo}}`, the router stores the model in the `content` property of the controller. Since `PostController` will by default be an `ObjectController`, it also proxies the model's properties to `this`. Thus in your `post` template, you should bind to `description` via `{{content.description}}` or just `{{description}}`.
- You can save yourself a few characters by loading your posts using the model hook in `PostsRoute`. Ember will install the results in the `content` property of `PostsController`, so you will need to update your template slightly.

[Here's the updated jsfiddle with the above changes](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/7UVkD/).